# dragAndDrop using webdriverio

Tags: webdriver-io

I have tried every single thing to perform dragAndDrop using webdriverio but nothing works. I have also posted a question in the webdriverio gitter but no response. below posted code is one of the ways I tried and its supposed to work but it just doesn't!

```
`   await this.driver.moveToObject(source); 
    await sleep(2000);
    await this.driver.buttonDown(0);
    await sleep(2000);
    await this.driver.moveToObject(destination);    
    await sleep(2000);
    await this.driver.buttonUp(0);`
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `moveTo` and `moveToObject` are deprecated or will be soon. They want you to start using `browser.actions()` instead. I don't have a solid example of this yet as I haven't had to implement this using the new protocol. If no one answers this by tonight I'll see if I can throw an example together. If you are comfortable working in the REPL I suggest reading the docs and playing in there to see if you can figure it out. You can find more info here http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/actions.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what properties are on the `source` and `destination` objects you are using but here is an example of how I was able to get it to work using the same commands you are trying.

In my example I have a table with columns that can be re-ordered by dragging and dropping them wherever I want them to be. First I get the two column headers I want to switch

```
let docIdHeader = browser.element('div[colid="documentid1"]');
let pageCountHeader = browser.element('div[colid="_PAGE_COUNT1"]');
```

If I log these objects out to the console I can see the properties stored in them.

```
> docIdHeader
{ sessionId: 'e35ae3e81f1bcf95bbc09f120bfb36ae',
  value:
   { ELEMENT: '0.3568346822568915-1',
     'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.3568346822568915-1' },
  selector: 'div[colid="documentid1"]',
  _status: 0 }

> pageCountHeader
{ sessionId: 'e35ae3e81f1bcf95bbc09f120bfb36ae',
  value:
   { ELEMENT: '0.3568346822568915-2',
     'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.3568346822568915-2' },
  selector: 'div[colid="_PAGE_COUNT1"]',
  _status: 0 }
```

Now using the same technique you are using and the selector property off of these objects I can get it to work in two ways.

```
browser.dragAndDrop(docIdHeader.selector, pageCountHeader.selector);
```

Or

```
browser.moveToObject(docIdHeader.selector)
browser.buttonDown(0)
browser.moveToObject(pageCountHeader.selector)
browser.buttonUp(0)
```

I ran this in the REPL interface so I know it works as I could see each step being executed after I sent the commands. If you are not familiar with how to use the REPL I highly recommend learning. You can play around with commands in the console until you figure something out and then add those commands to your tests.

Also, as I stated in my comments above. `dragAndDrop()` and `moveToObject()` are going to be deprecated soon and you will likely see a lot of warnings about it when you use these. The correct way to implement a drag and drop action going forward is to use `browser.actions()`. Unfortunately, I don't have an example of how to do it that way as I haven't played with it yet. If no one provides an example by tonight I will try to get one together for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)   I have used 'xpath' to identify elements- source and destination. You're example might help, I haven't tried it out yet :) Also, Thanks for the suggestion, I will have to check out about REPL! And regarding 'Actions', I have tried that too but it dint work as I expected it to. But again, I'm not 100% sure whether I've implemented Actions correctly or not!

Comment: Hey there! I have tried doing what you suggested in your example but it gives out an error saying ' selector needs to be typeof `string`'. Any idea whats going wrong here??

Comment: Also, when I log the objects (e.g- docIdHeader and pageCountHeader), I get the following things in selenium reponse: sessionId, Status and value but no "selector" :/ I cant understand why this happens!!

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to get the elements? I'm not really sure why that would happen unless the element wasn't found. You should get an element not found error though if that is what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this issue wherein the cursor doesn't move to the destination object after `buttonDown` and using `moveToObject` twice worked for me.

```
    await this.driver.moveToObject(source); 
    await this.driver.buttonDown(0);
    await this.driver.moveToObject(destination);    
    await this.driver.moveToObject(destination);   
    await this.driver.buttonUp(0);
```